# How to change Windows Server 2012 WSFC cluster group FailoverThreshold default value

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server-2012

I have WSFC on windows server 2012 and a Sql Server 2012 AlwaysOn HA on top. I need to change the default FailoverThreshold value from default.

I can see the values using the following command below is just a sample

Get-ClusterGroup FileServer1 | fl *

Cluster                : Cluster1

IsCoreGroup            : False

OwnerNode              : node1

State                  : Online

Name                   : FileServer1

Description            :

PersistentState        : 0

**FailoverThreshold      : 4294967295**

**FailoverPeriod         : 6**

AutoFailbackType       : 0

FailbackWindowStart    : 4294967295

FailbackWindowEnd      : 4294967295

AntiAffinityClassNames : {}

Id                     : 189ec8ad-1831-4f57-9bb0-3ffb9cbb9227

I need to change the FailoverThreshold and/orFailoverPeriod.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to change the default value for "FailoverThreshold" to value "2" for your example above, the Syntax would be (with Windows PowerShell):

**(Get-ClusterGroup -Name "FileServer1").FailoverThreshold=2**

To verify these Settings:

**Get-ClusterGroup -Name "FileServer1" | Select-Object Cluster, Name, GroupType, FailoverThreshold, FailoverPeriod**

Greetings Haecki

Answer (score 0):

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh710040.aspx I think you can change the always on value per the ms article